# Linear regression from two meta-analysis outcomes in R metafor

Tags: r, regression, meta-analysis, meta-regression

First of all, I am sorry if this question sounds very basic, but I am new in meta-analysis and statistics and I don’t know how to execute what I have in mind. 
I have a dataset of 60 experiments with two different types of measurements (biomass and temperature) under control and increased CO2 concentration (the treatment).

For biomass: I have calculated the effects of CO2 on biomass as

```
escalc(measure=“ROM”, m1i=elev.biomass.mean, m2i=control.biomass.mean, sd1i=elev.SD, sd2i=control.SD, data=data)
```

For temperature: I have calculated the effects of CO2 on temperature as

```
escalc(measure=“ROM”, m1i=elev.temp.mean, m2i=control.temp.mean, sd1i=elev.SD, sd2i=control.SD, data=data)
```

Therefore I have to meta-analysis with their respective effect size (ESbiomass, EStemp) and variance (VARbiomass, VARtemp). Next, I want to analyse the relationship between the CO2 effects on biomass and the CO2 effects on temperature to determine if there is a negative relationship between them (i.e. are the effects of CO2 on temperature negative when the effects of CO2 on biomass are positive?).

Of course I could use `lm (biomass.yi ~ temperature.yi)` but I want to use user defined weights for each experiment `weightsTime`.

My question is: i) How can I analyse the relationship `biomass.yi ~ temperature.yi` while taking into account the weights of the experiments in the context of a meta-analysis?; ii) How can I represent the relationship in a graph showing point sizes based on the weights and the model fit?

Comment: Do you have within study correlations between biomass and temperature?

Comment: @mdewey correlations are not given, should/can I calculate them?